# Acumatica get all rows in grid

Tags: acumatica

I am new to Acumatica.

In a FormDetail screen, I have a business process to process all the rows(Inserted, Modified, Unchanged) in the grid. I could not get the Unchanged rows. How to Solve this ?

Please Help
Thanks
Babu

Answer (score 3):

In Acumatica framework grids are bound to data views. You can call the 'Select' method of the data view to get all data rows.

First locate the graph and data view you are interested in. You can use the inspect element feature and then click on the grid to get that information:
[image]

For this example, the Transactions data view is located in SOOrderEntry graph:
[image]

So we would create a graph extension for SOOrderEntry and inside the graph we can iterate on Transactions collection. Notice that we use Base to access the base graph data view from the graph extension context:

```
foreach (SOLine soLine in Base.Transactions.Select())
{
}
```